# What happens when I 'git pull --rebase origin development' from within a feature branch?

Tags: git, rebase, feature-branch

Let's say I have a feature branch called `FeatureA`, and it is out of sync with (remote) `development` on which it is based. Normally I would rebase my branch by calling `git rebase development` (after syncing my local development with `origin/development` naturally).

Today, I do it different and call `git pull --rebase origin development` from my feature-branch instead. Now, what is the difference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`git pull --rebase origin development` is a shortcut to these commands:

```
git fetch origin development
git rebase origin/development
```

That is, fetch `origin/development` and then rebase the current branch on top of it.

**UPDATE**

As [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) pointed out:

> Yes, except that the two-argument version of fetch does not update origin/development in git 1.8.3 or earlier. (The rebase result is the same, but origin/development does not move.)

Comment: Yes, except that the two-argument version of `fetch` does not update `origin/development` in git 1.8.3 or earlier.  (The rebase result is the same, but `origin/development` does not move.)

Comment: Actually, as I note in the long answer below, it still rebases onto the correct point, it just does it by the SHA-1 ID stored in the `FETCH_HEAD` reference.  It's not easy to explain, but it "does the right thing" anyway!

Comment: @torek Oh I see, I just quoted you verbatim then, that's the most accurate, no point paraphrasing.

Answer (score 12):

Short version: if the rebase goes well, it works fine.  If not, it still works as well as it should, it just might be a bit confusing in a graphical viewer.

---

As always, `git pull` is basically `git fetch` followed by ... well, in this case, `git rebase` rather than `git merge`.  So:

- fetch from `origin`
- fetch only the `development` branch and put that in `FETCH_HEAD`
- then, instead of `git merge <commit-ID-from-FETCH_HEAD>`, use `git rebase` with that ID

So let's say the commit graph in your local tree looks like this (we'll assume you ran a `git fetch` at some point that updated `origin/development` with their commits `E` and `F`):

```
        C - D   <-- FeatureA
      /
A - B           <-- development
      \
        E - F   <-- origin/development
```

And, let's further assume that on `origin`, there's one more commit now on their branch named `development`.  The `fetch`-from-origin step will pick it up and make `FETCH_HEAD` point to that, so let's draw it in as node `G`:

```
        C - D       <-- FeatureA
      /
A - B               <-- development
      \
        E - F       <-- origin/development
              \
                G   <-- FETCH_HEAD
```

(If your git is new enough, 1.8.4 or later, `origin/development` will also be updated at this time, to point at node `G`.  If not, your local copy of their `development`, stored in your `origin/development`, lags behind.  It won't really matter for the rebase, it will just change how you'll see the results in a `git log --graph` view or a graphical commit-tree viewer.)

Now the `rebase` will copy your `FeatureA` commits in the usual method for a rebase, and make `FeatureA` point to the copies, abandoning the original commits.  We'll call the rebased ones `C'` and `D'`:

```
        C - D       [abandoned]
      /
A - B               <-- development
      \
        E - F       <-- origin/development
              \
                G   <-- FETCH_HEAD
                  \
                    C' - D'   <-- FeatureA
```

If you run a plain `git fetch` at this point, or if you have the newer-enough git so that `origin/development` has moved; and if we drop the "abandoned" parts and simplify the drawing, it becomes:

```
A - B               <-- development
      \
        E - F - G   <-- origin/development
                  \
                    C' - D'   <-- FeatureA
```

If you fast-forward-merge your local branch-label `development` to match `origin/development`, it's even simpler to draw (drop the kink down from B to E and put both `development` and `origin/development` to the right of the arrow pointing to `G`).

Comment: Thx! This is indeed very well explained!